# Is there an 'Unresolved' in Angular Material (like in Polymer)?

Tags: css, angularjs, material-design, angular-material

I remember that in Polymer there's an `unresolved` pseudo-selector attached to the body that allows for loading it only after things have been resolved by Polymer. Is there an alternative for that for Angular Material?

Comment: If you just want to hide an element before Angular has a chance to execute use `ng-cloak` as an attribute. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To hide an element before Angular has loaded, put `ng-cloak` as an attribute in the element.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

You may also have to put the following in your css (Angular Material already includes this in it's default css.)

```
ng-cloak { display: none !important; }
```